# MacBook boots up with less than one frame per second

Tags: macos, startup

This is what booting my MacBook looks like: [Macbook booting very slowly (youtube)](https://youtu.be/Rnxl1_E_f3Q)

I tried a PRAM reset, which was successful (it reseted the speaker volume and now plays the startup sound, which it didn't before), but that didn't fix the issue.

This is an early 2013 15'' Retina Mac, and I'm running El Capitan.

I really need this device, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In that video you have like 6 things plugged into your macbook. Try unplugging all of them except magsafe power, then try again.

Comment: Hardware issue I think. Try running Apple Diagnostics.

Comment: @owlswipe those were my keyboard, LAN, headphones and a monitor. While plugging those out didn't help, disabling FileVault in the recovery OS allows me to write this comment on my Macbook right now. Running Apple Diagnostics now.

Comment: @CrushedPixel OK. I wonder if filevault could be your issue? Do you have anything unusual like a ridiculously long password or something?

Comment: I don't think FileVault was the issue. My PW is of usual length, I'd say (less than 64 characters). Loading the Bootcamp menu is unusually slow now, but I don't have any other startup issues anymore.

Comment: Is it possible that my builtin SSD is dying? I ran Hardware diagnostics, but it got stuck at "less than 1 minute remaining" so I shut it down after an hour.

Answer (score -2):

Try also the SMC reset, doing it 2 or 3 times does not hurt:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295